# I'm getting the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'drawBox' of undefined, Can anyone spot the issue?

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to javascript and I am trying to use a HTML 5 canvas, Im trying to have a text box print to the screen and I can't seem to figure out what my issue is.
The error I'm getting in the chrome javascript console is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'drawBox' of undefined"

```
var Box = Box || function(x, y, title, desc){
    Box.commonMethod.setup(x, y, title, desc);
};

function init(){
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = "Black";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,150,75);
    var b = new Box(10,10,'hello', 'this is text');
    b.commonMethod.drawBox(ctx);
}

Box.commonMethod = {

        locx: 25,
        locy: 25,
        desc: "",
        title: "",
        width: 100,
        height: 100,

  setup: function(x, y, title, description){
    this.locx = x;
    this.locy = y;
    this.title = title;
    this.desc = description;
  },

  drawBox: function(ctx){
      ctx.font = "15px Arial";
      ctx.fillRect(this.x,this.y, this.width+2, this.height);
      ctx.fillStyle = "White";
      ctx.fillRect(this.x+1,this.y+1, this.width, this.height-2);
      ctx.fillStyle = "black";
      ctx.fillText(this.title, this.x, this.y+15);
      ctx.fillText(this.desc, this.x, this.y+40);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object instances (i.e. `b` in your case) don't pick up methods that are attached to their constructors (i.e. `Box` in your case). But they pick up methods on the constructor's **prototype**.

The correct way to define common properties/methods for object instances is to define them as part of the constructor's prototype:

```
Box.prototype.commonMethod = { ...
```

If you do this change, the following line of code will work:

```
b.commonMethod.drawBox(ctx);
```

But, then you'll have to also tweak your constructor to:

```
var Box = Box || function(x, y, title, desc){
    this.commonMethod.setup(x, y, title, desc);
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! That gets rid of the error. Now I just have to figure out why its not actually drawing that box... Do you know any comprehensive resources online that would give me a good understanding of how javascript works?

Comment: My pleasure! In your `setup` function you're assigning `locx` and `locy` while in the `drawBox` method you're using `x` and `y`.